# Cannot bulk load error message

Tags: syntax-error, ssms, bulkinsert

Attempting to do a bulk insert. The sample data and the format file are given below. It was brought to my attention that we need to use a Universal naming convention (UNC) hence why the '\FR-6RSGJH2.xyz.st\C$  item in the code. However, the same error occurs if you simply it to '\C\Users\myname\Desktop\testimport.csv'. Any ideas as to what is missing in the syntax or any settings changes that could be done?

```
  BULK INSERT testimport
  FROM '\\FR-6RSGJH2.xyz.st\C$\Users\myname\Desktop\testimport.csv'
  WITH (FORMATFILE = '\\FR- 
  6RSGJH2.xyz.st\C$\Users\myname\Desktop\format.txt')
  GO


  Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
  Cannot bulk load because the file 
  "\C\Users\myname\Desktop\testimport.csv" could not be opened. Operating 
  system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

Sample data

```
  32003012017010316
  32001022017040218
  32003032017030213
  32002042017020111
  32002052017020110
```

format file

```
 13.0
 5
 1     SQLCHAR     0     02     ""         1     st     ""
 2     SQLCHAR     0     03     ""         2     cnty   ""
 3     SQLCHAR     0     02     ""         3     v1     ""
 4     SQLCHAR     0     08     ""         4     date   ""
 5     SQLCHAR     0     02     "\r\n"     5     v2     ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it worked but when I made the testimport into a .txt versus a .csv, it worked. Anyways, that is the answer.